# track order of selected items in checkboxgroup for variable amount of options in Shiny

Tags: r, algorithm, user-interface, checkbox, shiny

I am using checkbox group as a tool for a user to select some parameters. The things displayed in the checkbox group is dynamic based on files some one uploads. I can get the selected checkboxes, but sometimes, the user needs to select them in a specific order, and shiny will only allow one order, the way it currently is. I'm not sure how to go about doing this, or if there is a widget in shiny that can do this for me. Thanks.

Comment: Try conditional checkboxes? http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

Comment: What is it exactly, you would like to achieve? Return the order, the user selected the checkboxes in a `checkboxGroupInput`?

You could improve this question if you provided a minimal example with the UI part and the desired output.

Comment: Not sure if I get you right, but the user should be able to define the order of things selected? In this case this widget could be helpful https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/036-custom-input-control